# Php add article to favourites

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a favourite button, so when users on my site click it and go off the website, and later come back on, the article they Favorited is still there. I have already created a membership system with php and mysql.

I have created a table for my favourting system, but could anyone suggest what columns to add to it?

Comment: Depends on what you want it to do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you would need is article ID field and a unique ID field.

Then what you would need to do is set a cookie when a visitor likes an article, in this cookie would be a unique ID for that user, then you could track exactly what articles they have liked.

Comment: thanks, but would I set the ID fields to any  value etc?

Comment: most likely auto increment?